# R plot of a matrix of complex numbers

Tags: r, matrix, plot, complex-numbers

I have a matrix of complex values.

If I issue the command:

```
plot(myMatrix)
```

then it shows on the graphics device a kind of scatterplot, with X-axis labeled Re(myMatrix) and Y-axis with Im(myMatrix). This shows the information I'm looking for, as I can see distinct clusters, that I cannot see with only one column.

My questions are :

1. I assume there is one point per matrix row. Is it right ?
2. How is calculated Re(myMatrix) for each row vector ?

It is not Re(myMatrix[1,row]), but seems to be a mix of all values of row vector. I would like to be able to get these values, so to know how to compute them with R.

Comment: Do you have any sample data?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is one point for each matrix element.

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(complex(real = rnorm(16), imaginary = rlnorm(16)), 4) 
plot(mat)

points(Re(mat[1,1]), Im(mat[1,1]), col = "red", pch = ".", cex = 5)
```

Look for the red dot:
[image: resulting plot]

You'd get the same plot, if you plotted a vector instead of a matrix, i.e., `plot(c(mat))`.

This happens because `plot.default` calls `xy.coords` and that function contains the following code:

```
else if (is.complex(x)) {
            y <- Im(x)
            x <- Re(x)
            xlab <- paste0("Re(", ylab, ")")
            ylab <- paste0("Im(", ylab, ")")
        }
        else if (is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x)) {
```

This means, that the fact that input is complex takes priority over it being a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question: Is there an easy way to tell to plot using a different color for each column ?

Comment: `plot(t(mat), col = seq_len(ncol(mat)))`